# Unable to set 'to' user using setAsync API of office.js

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

I'm writing a Outlook add-in, I've added `ReadWriteMailbox` permission. I'm able to get token & message details using `getCallbackTokenAsync` and `/v2.0/me/messages/` API. But when I try to set

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync(["test@test.comn"], function (result) {
          //code
 });
```

it is failing with below error

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync is not a function
TypeError: Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync is not a function

OS - Mac
Outlook- 16.72.*
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are using the API is compose mode? As Office.context.mailbox.item.to.setAsync is meant for compose mode.

Comment: I'm using MessageReadCommandSurface. I want to send selected mail to someone on click

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want to forward that message?

Comment: Yes exactly @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: The closest thing that is possible is displayReplyFormAsync or displayReplyAllFormAsync, but this creates a reply (and pops it up in an inspector). Otherwise, you could try and see if MakeEwsRequestAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) and the CreateItem command to create and send the forward does what you want.